# EntityFieldQuery - Order by the number of entity reference field values, matching a given array

Tags: 7, entities, database

I have a list of nodes (group), each referencing a number of other nodes (event) using an Entity Reference.

I can query the  the "group" using `$query->fieldCondition('field_group', 'tid', $group_tid);`.

However, I want to then "weight" the results based on the **A:** if they have a matching section. **B:** how many events match.

So, if I want all groups with the events `foo` and `bar`, and the data was

```
Group 1
   foo
Group 2
    foo
    bar
Group 3
 {no sections}
```

Then the results would be:

```
Group 2
Group 1
Group 3
```

Hopefully that makes some sense. Thanks for any help / advice!

Comment: i think i get what your asking.  is this of any help https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!database!select.inc/function/SelectQuery%3A%3AcountQuery/7  .  Apologies if not !

Comment: I think that is a great start, but I am not getting how you would use it with an EntityFieldQuery...

Comment: I think what you are doing is a bit too complex for an EFQ and would require either multiple steps, or a View.

Comment: I think you are right about it being too complex. Don't think views would be much help though.